# Flutter Firebase user authentication management across the application

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented user authentications successfully, everything is working fine, I just want to manage `currentUser` in an efficient way.

I want to login once and want to access the `currentUser` in app at any moment.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
```

is a `Future<FirebaseUser>`, I want to get instantly, I am unable to figure it out how to manage this, I think no need to add code for this, I am just seeking for an idea.

Answer (score 3):

As Sebastian stated, you should look into the [Provider](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&q=Provider+flutter) or any other state management tool/pattern, but for the example I am going to use you will need the Provider package.

Firebase Auth has an `onAuthStateChanged` stream that emits the current `FirebaseUser` if user is signed in or `null` if not signed in. so what you can do is wrap your `MaterialApp` with a `StreamProvider` and in any screen of your app you can access your user info

Example:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>(   //From the Provider package
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseUser fbUser = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); // this is how you can access the user from anywhere in the app
    return Scaffold(body: Container(child: Text(fbUser.uid ?? "No user"),),);
  }
}
```

Its worth noting that `onAuthStateChanged` is stream so if a logout or a login event occurs it immediately emits data according to that event.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package

Comment: It would be better to answer the question rather pointing to some other links or source. This is more comment than an answer.